# Receiving event Button in a Grid event from outside

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a custom control.
It consists of a Grid in which a Button is placed:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class clsButton : ContentView
    {
        private Grid _grid;
        private Button _button;

        public clsButton()
        {
            _grid = new Grid
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(0),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            };
            _grid.BindingContext = this; 

            _button = new Button()
            {
            };
            _button.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                //I tried different things here, but none gave me the right results. I need to "bubble" this click to the outside
                return;
            };

            _grid.Children.Add(_button, 0, 0);

            this.Content = _grid;
        }
    }
}
```

I create some of these custom controls in a ContentPage like this:

```
_MyButton = new clsImageButton()
{
};
var nTapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
nTapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += OnButtonClicked;
_MyButton.GestureRecognizers.Add(nTapGestureRecognizer);
```

And this is the void in the same ContentPage:

```
async void OnButtonClicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
     //I don't managed to get here
}
```

This doesn't work. 
"OnButtonClicked" is never called.

I think I have to raise an event from within the custom control.
I tried some things, but none of them were successful.

How would I do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your `clsButton`, declare a public event

```
public EventHandler ButtonClicked { get; set; }
```

then raise the event when your button is clicked

```
       _button.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
        {
          if (ButtonClicked != null) ButtonClicked(this,e);
        };
```

finally, where ever you are using `clsButton`, you can subscribe to the event (the gesture recognizer is not needed)

```
var btn = new clsButton();
btn.ButtonClicked += async (sender, e) => {
  // respond here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting the error "clsButton.ButtonClicked: The event property needs to have add and remove accessors". Do you perhaps mean "public EventHandler ButtonClicked { get; set; }"?

Comment: I managed to improve it. :-)  In the class:   

public EventHandler ButtonClicked; 
            _button.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                ButtonClicked?.Invoke(sender, e);
            };

Outside:
           _button.ButtonClicked += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                // respond here
                Debug.Assert(false);
            }; Can you please change your reply accordingly?

Comment: I think you need to remove "{ get; set; }". At least for me it doesn't work with it.